# Figma API JSON to PDF endpoint

Tags: php, json, pdf, figma

I'm using Figma API to get design files and those files are in JSON format, i want to edit the JSON and then export the design to pdf doing this manually is a hard task, there are some solutions where the design file is transformed to an image and then the image get printed to pdf but this is not what i want to achieve i want to have real nodes in pdf file like text nodes not a single image, i looked through figma REST API docs but i didn't find an endpoint that returns a PDF file when given json, is there another way yo achieve this ?

I tried converting the json to pdf manually but it's hard and i'm using php and pdf generation libraries are not that good, and there are more issues like fonts where you need to have every single font in order to get the pdf right but figma has this built in the editor but there is no endpoint for it in the REST API, i'm looking for another way to achieve this without printing a single image node to the pdf.

Comment: It would help readability if you put a period "." between sentences. That said, I don't understand what your programming question is. How would you want the PDF representation for a JSON file to look like? Why would the Figma REST API support such a conversion?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.